# Why do a Handler-Function only works anonymous in electron/node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Why is it possible to write in node (electron) something like this:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 480
    });
});
```

but this thows an error that `app is not ready`?

```
app.on('ready', onReady());

function onReady() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 480
    });
}
```

Comment: This could be wrong, but I think you just need to remove the function call... `app.on('ready', onReady)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're confusing function reference and function call.

Note that the function `onReady` returns nothing. By default this means it returns undefined.

So doing this:

```
app.on('ready', onReady());
```

Leads to this:

```
app.on('ready', undefined);
```

That is, the `onReady` function is called and it's result is passed to `app.on()`.

Basically what you've done is this:

```
app.on('ready', (function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 480
    });
})());
```

What you want instead is:

```
app.on('ready', onReady);
```

Comment: It was an *obvious* duplicate. *(not my dv)*

Comment: This is a good explanation of the issue.